# Websocket connections

Tags: react-native, asp.net-core

How do you make WebSockets connections between the application in React-Native and the server in Asp.Net Core?

The current SignalR in React-Native does not work with the version for Net Core.

Is it necessary to use a clean WebSocket on both sides?

Answer (score 0):

The released react-native-signalr library does not actually work with Net Core.

But the solution is in the JavaScript client `@aspnet/signalr` version `1.0.3`.

On the server, we also install `SignalR` in version `1.0.3`

Both sides must be compatible.

Example of use on the side of a mobile application:

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react'
import {
    View
    , StyleSheet
    , Text
    , Button
} from 'react-native'

import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';

export default class Settings extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            message: 'No messages.'
        };

        this.messageReceived = this.messageReceived.bind(this);

        const hubUrl = 'http://10.0.2.2:62954/chat';

        const connectionHub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(hubUrl)
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
            .build();

        connectionHub.on('ReceiveMessage', this.messageReceived);
        connectionHub.start()
            .catch(err => this.logError(err));

        this.connection = connectionHub;
    }

    messageReceived(message) {
        this.setState({
            message
        });
    }

    sendTestMessage() {
        this.connection.invoke('SendMessage', 'NameUser', 'Test message from mobile app.')
            .catch(err => this.logError(err));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
                <Text>{this.state.message}</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
                <Button title={"send"} onPress={this.sendTestMessage.bind(this)}>
                </Button>
            </View>
        </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
        , backgroundColor: '#0a3c63'
    , }
, });
```

Server site as recommended by SignalR documentation